# NuGet restore in VSTS always takes over 2 minutes

Tags: azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

In VSTS my nuget restore tasks has a 2 minute pause, with this log:

```
2017-12-26T21:20:51.7164100Z [command]d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64\nuget.exe restore d:\a\1\s\MarketMaking.sln -Verbosity Detailed -NonInteractive -ConfigFile d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_1748.config
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0823030Z NuGet Version: 4.3.0.4406
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0823494Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.4.8.50001' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0823786Z MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0824353Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe "d:\a\_temp\NuGetScratch\wn5wzq0b.1ki.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="d:\a\_temp\NuGetScratch\zpip1pyk.mzi.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.3.0\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="d:\a\1\s" /p:RestoreConfigFile="d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_1748.config"
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0824650Z 
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0824770Z Restoring NuGet package Antlr.3.5.0.2.
2017-12-26T21:23:01.0825025Z Restoring NuGet package Autofac.4.6.0.
```

So my question is, what is `MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000` and can I turn it off to get my 2 minutes back per build?

Comment: Note: I'm using NuGet version 4.3 because we're using authenticated package feeds for internal packages.

Comment: This search for NuGet issues on GitHub shows this line showing up in many recent issues: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/search?q=MSBuild+P2P+timeout+%5Bms%5D%3A+120000&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: What's the result if you restore package on local machine manually (call nuget.exe)? Can you reproduce this issue with a simple project?

Comment: "MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000" is just the information about timeout settings. For your issue, did you use Hosted agent or private agent?

Comment: Hosted agent.  I do plan to try to reproduce it with a simple project.  I plan to try it with a bug report for EF Core.

Comment: You'd better narrow down the issue, then report the issue.